# ResourceDictionary applying Source throws exception

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

Simple code:

```
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
Uri source = new(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/ResourceDictionary1.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
dict.Source = source;
```

Throws exception:

> Cannot locate resource from 'pack://application:,,,/Resources/ResourceDictionary1.xaml'.
> Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in WinRT.Runtime.dll
> Unknown error

`ResourceDictionary1.xaml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:EEA_Converter_Tool.Resources"
    x:Name="TestDict">
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The file exists, the path is correct. File location is:

```
ProjectFolder/Resources/ResourceDictionary1.xaml
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this:

```
Uri source = new("ms-appx:///YOURAPPNAME/Resources/ResourceDictionary1.xaml");
```

Comment: new("ms-appx:///Resources/ResourceDictionary1.xaml"); works perfectly for me. Btw what do you mean by 'YOURAPPNAME'? Is it Assembly name or?

Comment: yes, assemblyname